# phalcon run cmd file

Tags: php, phalcon

i can't run a php file with cmd.exe (windows 7) on any php files inside the phalcon application.

When i try to run a command the output is that it doesn't find classes.

For example: i have a php file that contains the following code

```
namespace Res\Helper
use Engine\Helper;

class MyClass extends Helper
{
   public function __construct()
   {}

   public function testme()
   {
      return 'WORKS';
   }
}
```

When i run in cmd php MyClass.php it says that the class Engine is not found!

Comment: i've used phalcon cli and now the classes are loaded but the problem is that i can't start a websocket server. i run php -q MyClass.php and noting is printed without errors but the server wont start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your namespace Engine is not properly registered. Phalcon's namespaces starts with Phalcon.

About engine, the only thing what I can think of is namespace Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\ but it does not have Helper. You probably got this code from some other place, then Phalcon documentation.

All possible namespaces can be viewed in stubs:

[image]

By the way,

Start using Linux for development.. I'm using Windows as my OS too, but Vagrant or any other virtual machine is always serving PHP code..

If you want, try my Vagrant config files:

Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # Base Box
  # --------------------
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

  # Connect to IP
  # --------------------
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.5.0"

  # Forward to Port
  # --------------------
  #config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Optional (Remove if desired)
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    # How much RAM to give the VM (in MB)
    # -----------------------------------
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "700"]

    # Uncomment the Bottom two lines to enable muli-core in the VM
    #v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
    #v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ioapic", "on"]
  end

  # Provisioning Script
  # --------------------
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "init.sh"

  # Synced Folder
  # --------------------
  #config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant/", :mount_options => [ "dmode=777", "fmode=666" ]
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/", :mount_options => [ "dmode=775", "fmode=644" ], :owner => 'www-data', :group => 'www-data'

end
```

init.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Using Precise32 Ubuntu
# to use closest ubuntu mirror by geographic location
echo 'deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse' | cat - /etc/apt/sources.list > temp && mv temp /etc/apt/sources.list
echo 'deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse' | cat - /etc/apt/sources.list > temp && mv temp /etc/apt/sources.list
echo 'deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse' | cat - /etc/apt/sources.list > temp && mv temp /etc/apt/sources.list
echo 'deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse' | cat - /etc/apt/sources.list > temp && mv temp /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-get update

#
# For PHP 5.5
#

sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update

#
# MySQL with root:<no password>
#
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -q -y install mysql-server

#
# PHP
#
sudo apt-get install -y php5 php5-dev apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-curl php5-mcrypt php5-gd php5-imagick

#
# Redis
#
sudo apt-get install -y redis-server

#
# MongoDB
#
sudo apt-get install mongodb-clients mongodb-server

#
# Utilities
#
sudo apt-get install -y curl htop git-core gcc autoconf
sudo apt-get install -y libpcre3-dev

#
# Redis Configuration
# Allow us to Remote from Vagrant with Port
#
sudo cp /etc/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.bkup.conf
sudo sed -i 's/bind 127.0.0.1/bind 0.0.0.0/' /etc/redis/redis.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server restart

#
# MySQL Configuration
# Allow us to Remote from Vagrant with Port
#
sudo cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.bkup.cnf
# Note: Since the MySQL bind-address has a tab character I comment out the end line
sudo sed -i 's/bind-address/bind-address = 0.0.0.0#/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf

#
# Grant All Priveleges to ROOT for remote access
#
mysql -u root -Bse "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
sudo service mysql restart



#
# Composer for PHP
#
sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

#
# Apache VHost
#
cd ~
echo '<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/public
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/public">
        Options Indexes Followsymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
' > vagrant.conf

sudo mv vagrant.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo a2enmod rewrite

#
# Install PhalconPHP
# Enable it
#
cd ~
git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install

echo "extension=phalcon.so" > phalcon.ini
sudo mv phalcon.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod phalcon
sudo php5enmod curl

#
# Install PhalconPHP DevTools
#
cd ~
echo '{"require": {"phalcon/devtools": "dev-master"}}' > composer.json
composer install
rm composer.json

sudo mkdir /opt/phalcon-tools
sudo mv ~/vendor/phalcon/devtools/* /opt/phalcon-tools
sudo ln -s /opt/phalcon-tools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon
sudo rm -rf ~vendor


#
# PHP.ini params edits
#
sudo echo "; ######### PHP.ini modifications from vagrant init.sh #######" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sudo echo "error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sudo echo "display_errors = On" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

#
# Reload apache
#
sudo a2ensite vagrant
sudo a2dissite 000-default
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service mongodb restart

#echo -e "----------------------------------------"
#echo -e "To create a Phalcon Project:\n"
#echo -e "----------------------------------------"
#echo -e "$ cd /var/www"
#echo -e "$ phalcon project projectname\n"
#echo -e
#echo -e "Then follow the README.md to copy/paste the VirtualHost!\n"

#echo -e "----------------------------------------"
#echo -e "Default Site: http://192.168.5.0"
#echo -e "----------------------------------------"

####### writable Volt directory
sudo mkdir /vagrant/cache/volt/
sudo chmod 777 /vagrant/cache/volt/
```

Add both files to some directory and with Windows power shell type. You have to install vagrant and virtual box before doing these.

```
vagrant up --provision
```

it will install ubuntu box, add Phalcon, php, mongodb, sql etc. to it. Your site's link will be: 192.168.5.0 you can add any domain in your host file (on windows/linux/mac) to point to this ip and you will be able to work with normal domain.

cheers!

Comment: i understand this, thanks for the heads up. I'm using linux from my VirtualBox. The problem is that when i try to start a server with linux it doesn't start. I have ratchet installed and when i run it with cmd on windows it works but when i run the same command line from linux shell it doesn't start the server nor display any error message.

Comment: I've added vagrant info, so you can copy-paste my files and you will be able to work with linux on your windows without any pain-points. How I've said already, Engine\Helper is not registered namespace and it's not part of phalcon. Please accept answer, if it's useful.